# How to shut down processes that slow down a Lenovo X1

Tags: windows-10

I got a new Lenovo X1 and when it starts up it runs fine.  After a few hours I noticed a bunch of additional processes start up.  Is anyone familiar with any of them?  Does anyone know a good Windows 10 maintenance or anti-virus software to keep them off my laptop?

OfficeClickToRun.exe

PowerMgr.exe

redirector.exe

RegSrvc.exe

RstMwService.exe

RtkAudUService64.exe

RuntimeBroker.exe

SearchIndexer.exe

SearchUI.exe

SecurityHealthSystray.exe

services.exe

SettingSyncHost.exe

SgrmBroker.exe

ShellExperienceHost.exe

shtctky.exe

smartscreen.exe

smss.exe

SynTPEnh.exe

taskhostw.exe

Taskmgr.exe

WindowsInternal.Composabl

WinStore.App.exe

WmiPrvSE.exe

WTabletServiceISD.exe

WUDFHost.exe

WWAHost.exe

Comment: general rule of thumb: uninstall what you do not need, turn of automatic startup of programs that you want to keep, but that do not necessary need to be startup at boot time, leave the rest as is (installed and initialized at startup) in case they are needed by the system itself.

Answer (score 0):

None of those look like viruses. Most of them I recognize as legitimate software, either related to software normal to find on a modern computer, or driver utilities.

Your OS already has built in Anti-virus as well. Windows Defender works just fine.

While it's a good idea to know what is running on your computer, it's only helpful knowing that IF you can take the time to understand what those processes are. You should be able to look up any of those process names online to learn what they are and what they belong to.